# Able to call API from Postman but not Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post

I created a call in Angular to reach the API method: AddUpdateInternalNotes

**API (c#)**:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(ResponseDTO))]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Pt/AddUpdateInternalNotes")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddUpdateInternalNotes([FromBody] PtInternalNotesDTO ptInternalNotes)
    {
        try
        {
            if (AppSettings.TraceWriter) Configuration.Services.GetTraceWriter().Info(Request, "PController-REQUEST LOG-", "AddUpdateInternalNotes");


            ResponseDTO response = PtManager.AddUpdateInternalNotes(db, ptInternalNotes);
            return await Task.FromResult(Ok(response));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

I am able to successfully call it from Postman if I put JSON in the body.

However, when I try to call it from Angular, the API does not seem to get triggered.

**Angular**:

```
let newInternalNote: IPInternalNotes = {
        PID             : 51,
        CreatedBy       : 57,
        Note            : "Some text",
        CreatedByText   : "OtherText",
        CreateDate      : "2022-02-20 16:57:49.140",
        ModifiedBy      : null, ModifiedByText: null, ModifiedDate: null, DeleteDate: null, DeletedBy: null, DeletedByText: null
    };
    this.ps.AddUpdatePtInternalNotes(newInternalNote).subscribe(resp => { });

public AddUpdatePtInternalNotes(ptInternalNotes: IPtInternalNotes): Observable<ResponseDTO> {
    let url = environment.API_URL + '/api/Pt/AddUpdateInternalNotes';
   
    return this.http.post<ResponseDTO>(url, ptInternalNotes).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you call `subscribe` on the `Observable` returned by `AddUpdatePtInternalNotes`?

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă I just added the subscribe and it is reaching the API now, but the debugger is saying the object has either 0 or null for all of its properties. It doesn't look like the actual values are being sent